# How to center multiple objects within a box?

Tags: java

I'm trying to center multiple images within a box. The images being rendered are players, and the box is a tile. I want it so that there's more space between the players the fewer there are, and less space between them the more there are, but they're always centered within the tile. Here's the code I have currently, but it only works with 1 or 2 players on a tile:

```
public Point getPlayerPos(Tile tile)
{
    Point tilePos = tile.getPosition();
    int xPos = tilePos.x + (tile.getImage().getWidth() / 2 - image.getWidth() / 2);
    int yPos = tilePos.y + (tile.getImage().getHeight() / 2 - image.getHeight() / 2);
    return new Point(xPos, yPos);
}

public Point getPosOnTile(Tile tile)
{
    List<Player> tilePlayers = getPlayersOnTile(tile);

    Point pos = getPlayerPos(tile);
    int xPos = pos.x, yPos = pos.y;

    xPos -= (tilePlayers.indexOf(this) + 1) * image.getWidth();

    int totalWidth = 0;
    for (Player player : tilePlayers)
        totalWidth += player.getToken().getImage().getWidth();

    xPos += (tile.getImage().getWidth() / 2 + totalWidth / (tilePlayers.size() * 2));

    return new Point(xPos, yPos);
}
```

This is within the Player class, so image refers to the player image, and it's the same as player.getToken().getImage().